# How do I create class instances using values from a list of dicts in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class setup:

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, name="", attack=0, defense=0, magic=0, shield=0, description=""):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = int(attack)
        self.defense = int(defense)
        self.magic = int(magic)
        self.shield = int(shield)
        self.description = description
```

I would like to make instances of `Card` using a list of dictionaries created from `csv.dictreader`.

Here is what the method for determining my `cardList` returns:

```
[
{'Magic': '200', 'Shield': '100', 'NameOfCard': 'Knight', 'Attack': '700', 'Defense': '400', 'Description': ''},
{'Magic': '500', 'Shield': '500', 'NameOfCard': 'Mage', 'Attack': '0', 'Defense': '0', 'Description': ''},
{'Magic': '100', 'Shield': '100', 'NameOfCard': 'Peasant', 'Attack': '100', 'Defense': '100', 'Description': ''},
{'Magic': '0', 'Shield': '0', 'NameOfCard': 'Lancer', 'Attack': '400', 'Defense': '100', 'Description': ''},
{'Magic': '100', 'Shield': '200', 'NameOfCard': 'Guardian', 'Attack': '100', 'Defense': '600', 'Description': ''},
...]
```

I was hoping to be able to use the `'NameOfCard'` values to name the instances, and then map the values to the arguments taken by the `__init__` method in the `Card` class.

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
Knight = Card(cardList[0]('NameOfCard')...)
```

But calling `print Knight.name` returns `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`.

**How do I use my list of dicts to create instances of the `Card` class?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use argument unpacking:

```
knight = Card(**dict_of_properties)
```

This will expand `dict_of_properties` into named arguments:

```
knight = Card(name='foo', stuff='bar')
```

Assuming `dict_of_properties` looks like:

```
dict_of_properties = {
    'name': 'foo',
    'stuff': 'bar'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, just like the above answer too. I did not know about the `**` ability.

Answer (score 2):

If the argument names were the same as the dict keys then you could use:

```
Knight = Card(**cardList[0])
```

As it is you'll need to map the dict keys to the proper argument names first.

Comment: I reworked the csv file to make the keys match. Thanks! I did not know about the `**` ability.